# Is there a way to get $_POST variables in a loop?

Tags: php

Is there a way to make a loop that would give me this, depending on the number of users I want to grab?

```
$user1 = htmlentities($_POST['user1']);
$user2 = htmlentities($_POST['user2']);
$user3 = htmlentities($_POST['user3']);
```

I've tried this:

```
while ($i <= $useramm) {
    ${"user$i"} = htmlentities($_POST['user-' + $i]);
    $i=$i+1;
}
```

but it shows me these errors:

> Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 14

Comment: Should be `$_POST['user-' . $i]`

Comment: `$i=$i+1;` could be `$i++;`

Comment: `.` concatenates strings in PHP :)

Comment: $i is empty on the first run.

Comment: Should it be user1 or user-1 ? And yes, as others have mentioned use . for concatenation.

Comment: `${"user$i"} = htmlentities($_POST['user' . $i]);`. Probably an array would be a better solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with variable variables, but you need to use concatenation operator instead of addition.

```
$i = 0;
while (++$i <= $useramm) {
    ${"user$i"} = htmlentities($_POST['user' . $i]);
}
```

A better way would be to use an array. Instead of numbering your field `user1`, `user2` and so on, just use array.

In your HTML define POST fields as the same name with `[]` at the end. PHP will parse this as an array with key `user`:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user[]" />
    <input type="text" name="user[]" />
    <input type="text" name="user[]" />
    <input type="text" name="user[]" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then in PHP you can just use the array values, either in a loop or directly accesing through an index.

```
foreach ($_POST['user'] as $singleUser) {
    // use $singleUser here
}
// or 
$_POST['user'][0]; // first user field
$_POST['user'][1]; // second user field
```